# Read facebook metaData using Shared URL

Tags: php, node.js, facebook

I have a very basic query
If I have a public URL of Facebook post and I Want to read body of the page in any case either meta data or whole Page HTML

I found few solution that works fine on my local machine and returns me with all the text on the page but the same script does not work on Server with IP

I tried few libraries like
https://github.com/nasa8x/html-metadata-parser

and tried to access facebook link, it does work fine on local machine but doesn't work on server IP

```
    const { parser } = require('./dist');
    
    
    (async () => {
    
        var result = await parser('https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=136132415454447&id=100071730670627&sfnsn=scwspmo');
    
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));
    
    })();
```

can you give me solution in any way PHP/NODE/Python

thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them.